# How to run a module from a different script in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a module with various functions that produces a number.

How would I call this module from a different script, such that I could call the module repeated times and use the number it produces?

Comment: do you mean import functions from it?

Comment: Functions are meant to be called from some other code. So you can import the module and call it's functions, not "run" the module.

Comment: @EugeneSh. strictly speaking, you *do* run the module when you `import` it, but this generally just amounts to running the function and class definitions.

Answer (score 3):

assuming the module is in the same directory as your script you can import it and then use the functions. say your module script `module.py` has a function `run()` which returns a number. in the other script use:

```
import module

number = module.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
import "module"

print(modul.function())
```

that would print you that what the function returns